# Algorithm for searching 2d array

Tags: ruby, algorithm

```
data = [[0,1], [1,6,10], [], [1,2,4,5], [7,8], [], [], [8], [2], [0,3], [9]]
```

Given the above  2d array,  I need to select five arrays that give me the most unique number.

For example

```
# returns 11 (optimal output,  the number of subclasses)
(data[1] | data[3] | data[4] | data[9] | data[10]).length 
# returns 10 (less optimal output)
(data[0] | data[1] | data[3] | data[4] | data[10]).length
```

Doing it the brute force way is taking way too much time to complete. 
Is there any other suggestion?

Comment: can you please explain it more clear

Comment: Does "most unique" mean "least duplication"? This is a permutation problem, so it's not going to be terribly efficient. There's no algorithms that magically solve this in a general case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a [greedy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greedy_algorithm) algorithm.

For each iteration, it simply takes the subarray with the most new elements. It works for your example, but might be off by a few elements for more complex examples.

For large arrays and large `n`, it should be much faster than any solution using `combination`.

You didn't provide any code, so I'll leave it as an exercise to look for counterexamples ;).

```
data = [[0, 1], [1, 6, 10], [], [1, 2, 4, 5], [7, 8], [], [], [8], [2], [0, 3], [9]]

def trim(array, already_taken)
  array.map { |sub_array| sub_array - already_taken }.reject(&:empty?)
end

def find_best_cover(array, n)
  array = array.map{ |subarray| subarray.uniq }
  Array.new(n) do
    next_best = array.max_by { |subarray| subarray.size }
    array = trim(array, next_best)
    next_best
  end
end

p find_best_cover(data, 5).flatten
#=> [1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 10, 7, 8, 0, 3, 9]
```

Answer (score 4):

Here's something that does it:

```
data = [[0,1], [1,6,10], [], [1,2,4,5], [7,8], [], [], [8], [2], [0,3], [9]]

best = data.combination(5).max_by do |combo|
  combo.flatten.uniq.length
end

best
# => [[1, 6, 10], [1, 2, 4, 5], [7, 8], [0, 3], [9]]
best.flatten.uniq.length
# => 11
```

It doesn't take long to compute, and there's probably better ways of optimizing that inner loop if you're prepared to use Benchmark for testing.

If you need orders of magnitude better performance, maybe a C++ library [linked in via FFI](https://github.com/ffi/ffi) is the answer.

If you're dealing with numbers that are relatively small, like in the range of 0..31 or even 0..63, then you could do this with bitmasks. That would reduce each array to a single value, and combining values with OR is trivial in terms of compute. Counting the number of bits in a given value is likewise pretty simple.

Comment: There are 12 numbers in the result, but only 11 _unique_ numbers (1 occurs twice).

Comment: BTW, I think you (only) need `combination`, not `permutation`.

Comment: @Stefan Great point, and it does run a lot faster that way. I didn't notice the duplication either, so that's also addressed.

Comment: @kouty I've updated the answer with Stefan's observations.

Answer (score 1):

You can reduce computation time by reducing your `data` array.

Initially, there are 462 combinations:

```
data.combination(5).size
#=> 462
```

Deleting empty arrays reduces this to 56:

```
data.reject!(&:empty)

data.combination(5).size
#=> 56
```

And deleting arrays that are fully contained in other arrays results in merely 6 combinations:

```
data -= [[2], [8]]

data.combination(5).size
#=> 6
```